# In NPM Workspaces / monorepo - is the "*" for the dependency version ok?

Tags: npm, monorepo

This seems to work,

```
{ "dependencies": { "my-local-dep": "*" } }
```

Instead of having bogus 0.0.1 version numbers stamped in.  Is this acceptable / problematic? If I run >npm update it does try to stamp the 0.0.1 from the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more than fine since that's your local library and you're carrying its development along within the monorepo. It makes sense that whenever you update that shared library the app inside the monorepo will get the latest version.  You can also use `"dependency": "latest"` but I usually go for "*", it's fine.

Again, all this reasoning is valid because we are talking about a monorepo environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this technique on a large setup, and it's totally fine.